# Is it possible to view csv and tsv files with column padding such that the columns align nicely?

Tags: csv, visual-studio-code

I'm aware that there exist extensions that provide an excel-like view of the file, but that is not what I'm looking for. I would like to work in the text editor, and have the columns visually aligned. Not by modifying the file to add padding spaces to the columns, but just visually, leaving the file intact.

Example:

```
H1,H2,H3
a,asdfasdf,b
aasdfas,b,asdsdfd
```

What I would like to see:

```
H1,      H2,       H3
a,       asdfasdf, b
aasdfas, b,        asdsdfd
```

Comment: click the `Open Preview` button in the top right of the editor

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Edit csv](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=janisdd.vscode-edit-csv):

[image: edit csv extension demo]

You can edit your files in a column-aligned view and then apply them to the underlying file.  It does look excel-like but it isn't modifying your file into columns.  I haven't found a lighter-weight extension to do the same thing.

Comment: excellent choice. on the way i found that the following works too in less GUI-like manner: select "Rainbow CSV: Align CSV columns"